# Как отправить правильный POST запрос с помощью xNet?

Tags: c#, xnet

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой которую решить еще не получилось, да и не встречал решений для xNet.
Я использую библиотеку xNet для C# чтоб работать с запросами.

**Тут 1 часть картинки**

**Обратите внимание** на параметр params={"network":30, "page":"1"}

Но у меня получается так:

**Тут 2 часть картинки**

Ясно что нужно как то закодировать, ибо этот же запрос выглядит в URL Decode

**Тут 3 часть картинки**

А вот сам код который отсылает запрос

**Тут 4 часть картинки**

Как решить данную проблему?
Библиотека xNet
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ответил разработчик.
Параметры задаваемые через AddParam кодируются. Чтобы они не кодировались, нужно использовать:

```
public HttpResponse Post(string address, RequestParams reqParams, bool dontEscape=false)
```

dontEscape в данном случае должен быть равен true. Либо же в Post можно просто передать строку.